# How do you get the value for an attribute when it's not your primary entity

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011

I am trying to write a plugin that will trigger when an account is created. If there is a originating lead I want to fetch the company name in the lead and put it in the account name field. What I'm not sure how to do is to obtain the information out of the lead entity.

I have the following code (I'll keep updating this)...

```csharp
Entity member = service.Retrieve("lead", 
    ((EntityReference)account["originatingleadid"]).Id, new ColumnSet(true));

if (member.Attributes.Contains("companyname"))
{
    companyName = member.Attributes["companyname"].ToString();
}

if (context.PostEntityImages.Contains("AccountPostImage") &&
    context.PostEntityImages["AccountPostImage"] is Entity)
{
    accountPostImage = (Entity)context.PostEntityImages["AccountPostImage"];

    companyName = "This is a test";

    if (companyName != String.Empty)
    {
        accountPostImage.Attributes["name"] = companyName;
        service.Update(account);
     }
 }
```

Comment: My guess is that you get stuck on the linked entity (*EntityReference*). Correct?

Comment: This is the first time doing this, so I'm pretty much stuck on everything.

Comment: By the way - will the account be created by an actual user using the GUI or is it an automated process? If it's the former, you might have a smoother solution in using JavaScript and simply pull out the data from *regarding* or *subject*.

Comment: It can be both, but the majority are created through a workflow

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not going to spoil the fun for you just yet but the general idea is to:

1. Catch the message of *Create*.
2. Extract the guid from your *Entity* (that's your created account).
3. Obtain the guid from its *EntityReference* (that's your lead).
4. Read the appropriate field from it.
5. Update the name field in your account.
6. Store the information.

Which of the steps is giving you issues? :)
As always, I recommend using query expressions before fetchXML. YMMV

Comment: Do I create a new guid for the new account, or are you talking about executing the plugin post create??

Comment: Yes, you are forced to catch the message on post-state (or maybe even async) if you are to obtain the guid for it. **Do not** try to assign a guid yourself (but I'm sure you already knew that).

Comment: @Gary Glad to be of help. Check it as an answer if we're done.

Comment: I don't have it working yet. I have updated my original post with my current code. I am receiving a "object reference not set to an instance of an object". I'm thinking that it has to do with obtaining the lead.

Comment: Two things. (1) Remember to make your code in the question nice. I've edited it for this time but try to keep it nice from the beginning. (2) I'm pretty certain that the error occurs because you're trying to read a field that isn't filled out. One expects that `new ColumnSet(true)` gets all the columns. It doesn't... It's that, or you're getting a *null* somewhere when you cast and try to read the value (e.g. `((Entity)blopp).Id` will give you this error if the cast fails resulting in *null*). Where exactly does the error occur? What line?

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I've resolved that problem of the object reference. My only issue left is that the account name is not being updated. The plugin runs without any errors but the update doesn't occurr. I've updated the code again to what I have currently. If there is no data in the field and you include it as a field in the image, is the field part of the attribute list or do you need to add it? I've updated to code to the current version.

Comment: @Gary Is the plugin registered on pre-state or post-state?

Comment: It is registered post-state

Answer (score 1):

Is lead connected to the account? Just use the IOrganizationService.Retrieve Method
To retrieve the correct lead (assuming you have the lead id from the account entity)..

Create the organizationService in the execute method of your plugin.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg334504.aspx

Also here is a nice example to write the plugin:

http://mscrmkb.blogspot.co.il/2010/11/develop-your-first-plugin-in-crm-2011.html?m=1